# Analyzing home network traffic using wireshark

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark

I am using wireshark to analyize my home netowrk traffic since it has become painfully slow (Slow download speeds) recently (restarting modem and MediaLink router didn't help, also upgraded the firmware).

So, in the wireshark IO graph, I see an unexpected pattern (not directly related to fixing the slow network issue, but might help in understanding how network works):

[image]

So, as I have annotated the graph:

1. How does playing a 1 HD (720) video causes the graph to have sudden spikes but after playing the 1080HD video, the spike is more prolonged and suddenly it drops.
2. I am not sure why did the graph flattened in the middle ?(the data was still being transferred but does it have to do with UDP packets and the machine received all the data packets)

Comment: What do you mean by "painfully slow"? Slow download speeds? Sites taking too much to load? Because looking at that graph it seems that for a while you lost connection completely. Since it's a home network I assume you can turn off the wireless/unplug LAN cables and leave only one computer connected, and then do the same in a different computer to see if the issue is in your network or with your connection with the ISP - which seems more likely, given that you seem to have lost connection for a while there. Also, visit `speedtest.net` and see if your results match the speed you adquired...

Comment: Updated: Slow download speeds

Comment: If you call your ISP they'll probably ask you to do the speed tests with only your computer connected to the network by an Ethernet cable. You should in fact to that, with two different computers as I mentioned, to see whether the problem resides on the network, on your computer or on your connection with the ISP. Wireshark is the correct tool only if you already know it's a network issue. If so, do some package monitoring to see if there's a specific client causing the problem. If everything looks okay it's probably a config issue, I'd just default everything if that isn't much of a hassle.